# Remove first number from Column MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a column that just has 4 numbers and I want to remove the first. I Run a update query I found on here but it says no columns affected.

```
 UPDATE mytable
 SET mycol = TRIM(LEADING '[0-9]' FROM mycol)
```

I don't get an error when I run it just does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test `mycol` has digit with `mycol RLIKE '^[0-9]'`, remove with `SUBSTRING(mycol, 2)`:

```
UPDATE mytable
 SET mycol = SUBSTRING(mycol, 2)
 WHERE mycol RLIKE '^[0-9]'
```

*Documentation:*

- [expr RLIKE pat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)
- [SUBSTRING(str,pos)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE `tablename`
SET `columnname` = 
TRIM(LEADING  'THE CHARACTER YOU WANT TO REMOVE, eg: 1'  FROM `columnname`);
```

Comment: Well ran what you had and got no Affected Rows.Then I ran //UPDATE mytable
SET siteid = 
TRIM(LEADING  '[0-9]'  FROM 'siteid');// and now the entire siteid column is set to siteid.